# What is a good way to let a C# program interact with a node.js application?

Tags: c#, node.js, socket.io

Recently I've been working on a twitch chat bot, developed in node.js using tmi.js. Since it has many functionalities, I want to ease the usage by creating a control panel/dashboard using C#.

I've found a similar question regarding this topic, though I wonder what would be a good solution to this problem is and if there is one, an in-depth explanation to the solution would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** As an example, I would like to be able to connect and disconnect the bot using the control panel.

**EDIT 2:** I've looked into socket servers so far, though I would need help understanding setting up the connection between the program and node.js application.

Comment: “Best” is subjective. You’d have to be quite specific so this question wouldn’t be either too broad or/and subjective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "best" way.  That's pretty much a matter of opinion which will vary according to experiences, requirements and just personal preference.  There are dozens of different good ways for two processes to communicate.  Any of them can work just fine for the relatively simple situation you describe.  I'll offer a couple of ideas.

First off, is there any reason you don't just add a web UI directly to the bot?  Then, you just have one program.  You can add a web interface to the bot that exposes a control panel interface.  node.js makes it pretty easy to add a web interface (probably use Express and your favorite template sub-system).  Then the web interface has direct access to the bot and can control it directly.

Second, if you have some compelling reason that the control panel should be a separate program, it could also be written in node.js using something like electron.

Third, if you insist on C# for the control program, then you just have to decide what TCP-based scheme you want to use for the two program to talk to one another.  For one way communication (control panel sending requests to the bot), you can expose a simple http interface on the bot and just send http requests to that interface from the C# control program.  One can create an http interface with a few control methods in your node.js program in literally about 5 minutes.  You'd then use whatever library C# gives you for sending http requests to another server.

If you want/need two way communication between bot and control panel so the bot can regularly send information to the control panel, then you could connect the two with a socket.io connection and then you'd have a continuous bi-directional communication channel open between the two.  You'd add a socket.io server to your node.js app and use a socket.io library in your C# application.  The C# application would then create the socket.io connection to your bot and you can then send data/commands either way over that connection.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. I would personally insist on writing a C# program, since it is my primary language and I absolutely suck at creating web interfaces. If you could elaborate on creating control methods in node, I would be very thankful. I'm sorry, that I require so much help, but this is my first time working on this kind of problem and I'm very new to node.

Comment: @bezunyl - It's a little out of scope here for me to add a tutorial on creating control methods in node.js.  The tools to use would be the Express framework for creating the web server and defining routes and then you'd probably use query parameters for sending requests and JSON as your data format for returning data if querying for data or post requests to send data.  I'd suggest you read a few tutorials on the Express framework.  It should take about 10 lines of code to get your first few API methods up and running.